# Can a Mirror Witch get multiple uses of Cryptic Omens?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

The text of Cryptic Omens reads as follows:

> Cryptic Omens (Ex): Each day, when a mirror witch consults with her patron mirror, the patron fragment can speak a few words of cryptic advice about the witch’s future. While the words are often obscure when the fragment utters them, they nearly always make sense to the witch at just the right moment aid her in dealing with the threats of the day. Once per day, after the witch receives this advice, she can gain one of the following benefits without taking an action: gain a +2 insight bonus on a saving throw she is about to attempt; gain a +2 insight bonus on a Bluff, Diplomacy, or Sense Motive check she is about to attempt; or instead of rolling initiative, treat her initiative as if she rolled a 12 on the die. She can’t use this last option if she can’t act during a surprise round. She doesn’t choose which benefit she gains while consulting the mirror; instead, she does so when she would be about to roll a saving throw, initiative check, or appropriate skill check.

A few other abilities state that you can expend a use of Cryptic Omens to use the ability (Greater Omens, Clairvoyance/Clairaudience, Scrying).

Is there a way to gain extra uses of this ability, or am I just misreading/misunderstanding what I'm reading? Saying that "you can expend A use" instead of "you can expend YOUR use," sort of implies it would be possible to gain another, am I over thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mirror witch](http://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Witch%20Mirror%20Witch) class feature **greater omens** says, "The number of times per day that the mirror witch can use cryptic omens increases by an amount equal to the Intelligence modifier of the patron mirror."

This will give the mirror witch a handful more cryptic omens uses per day.

Comment: My brain must have skipped that for some reason while reading.